# Generate random number to pass it through the form to database withh ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I want to generate a random number between 2 and 3 and pass that number through a form and insert it into database. The action will be done with ajax.

The problem I am facing is that since no page refresh occurs here only 2 gets into the database everytime I hit the button and 3 never comes. The number is not randomizing  since there is no page page refresh. For example:

```
$min=2;
$max=3;
$ad = rand($min,$max);

<form action="javascript:parseResponse('.$ad.');"  id="responseForm"  name="responseForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" id="textid">
<input type="submit" id="something">
</form>
```

Can anyone tell me what can I do?

Comment: if you to be safe user input doesnt temper with the rand calculation, you could just send an ajax request and let that request generate a random number and save it in the database and return the number so you can then show the number in the browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to generate a random number in Javascript. Try:

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 2;
```

This will generate a random number - either 2 or 3

And therefore change your form action to

```
javascript:parseResponse((Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to create a random integer with Javascript. That can be refreshed when you resubmit the form.

The PHP code will return a random integer, but it will not change untill the page is refreshed.

Comment: ok.but how will I attatch that integer to my form from javascript..please give an example..It will be more clear then..

Comment: Show more of your code, then a can explain it more easy. By the way: do you only want to add a 2 or 3 to a database? Why don't you add this code (PHP code for `rand(2,3)`) to the PHP script you're calling with Ajax?